# Meteor renaming Meteor.users collection name in MongoDB

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

We have more than one website which points to same MongoDB. For example front facing public website, internal admin website, etc.

We would like to have different users collection for different website. Is there any way to instruct Meteor to user different collection name in actual DB while accessing users collection using Meteor.users variable.

Comment: It's better if you use "application" word instead of "website"! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the source code it appears the collection name is hard coded in the `accounts-base` package. I don't see any options to set the name through code.

```
Meteor.users = new Mongo.Collection("users", {
      _preventAutopublish: true,
      connection: Meteor.isClient ?     Accounts.connection : Meteor.connection
});
```

Answer (score 1):

No, sadly this is hardcoded into the package and as Brian said, the package offers no room for customization.

However, you could very easily add a new key `accountType` for each document in the `Meteor.users` collection. `accountType` could specify whether that user belongs to the front facing public website, or the internal admin website.

For example, the user document:

```
{
  username: "Pavan"
  accountType: "administrator"
  // other fields below
}
```

And from there of course, you could publish specific data, or enable different parts of your website based on what `accountType`'s value is.

For example, if I want the administrators to be able to subscribe to, and see all user information:

```
Meteor.publish("userData", function() {
  if (this.userId) {
    if (Meteor.users.find(this.userId).accountType === "admin") {
      return Meteor.users.find();
    } else {
      return Meteor.users.find(this.userId);
    }
  } else {
    this.ready();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not tested, but from the first look, this could be a feasible way to change the name of user collection.  Place this code somewhere in /lib folder:

```
Accounts.users = new Mongo.Collection("another_users_collection", {
  _preventAutopublish: true,
});

Meteor.users = Accounts.users;
```

Comment: I test it, it surprisingly works with almost no problem. The only thing that do not work on my prototype is Meteor.user() so I assign the "new Mongo.Coll..." to a variable, and then assign that variable to Accounts.users, and export it to use it in other places where I need to call this collection manually. Thanks a lot.